# Players spamming jump does not trigger Touched" event

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm making a sort of spleef type game where players jump around as blocks disappear beneath them. However, if you just hold down the space bar, Roblox doesn't seem to register the "Touched" event. Can anyone help?

**Here is my script for each of the disappearing platforms:**

```
local platform = script.Parent

local function fade()
        print("Touched!")
        platform.Transparency = 1
        platform.CanCollide = false
end

platform.OnTouched:Connect(fade)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a very common "jump" issue happens in the touch zone. Where a player jumps it triggers the TouchEnded events. And here is my solution:
In my regular touch end check events there is:

```
-- This manages on touch end events
local function onTouchEnded(hit)
    
    -- Get hit player and check its humanoid 
    local player   = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    local humanoid = hit.Parent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    
    -- Sanity check on humanoid
    if humanoid then 

        -- Configure player status
        if player and PlayerDebounce[player] then
            
            
            if not isStillInVolume(player) then
                
                --print("left")
                
                -- Assigned the player to the debounce table
                PlayerDebounce[player] = nil

                -- Animation check on animation
                if not NpcGreetingsTrack.IsPlaying and not NpcWavingTrack.IsPlaying then

                    NpcWavingTrack:Play()

                end

                -- Fire remote events that player is in sight
                ActionRemoteEvent:FireClient(player, "Exit")
                
            end
        
        end
        
    end
    
end
```

Now for an additional sanity check I have created this helper function, and it was checked everytime a touchEnded event was triggered, where:

```
-- This tells if the player still is inside the interactive volume
local function isStillInVolume(player)
   
   -- Initialize return variable
   local returnMe = false
   
   -- Get NPC and player's exiting positions
   local NpcPosition    = rootpart.Position
   local playerPosition = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position
   
   -- Evaluate the relative position
   local relativePosition = playerPosition - NpcPosition
   
   -- In volume check
   if math.abs(relativePosition.x) <= VolumeBoundary_x then
       
       if  math.pow(relativePosition.z, 2) < BoundarySquare - math.pow(relativePosition.x, 2) and relativePosition.z > TanTen * math.abs(relativePosition.x)  then
               
           returnMe = true
       
       end
       
   end
   
   return returnMe
   
end
```

As you may notice, that my touch volume is a pie geometry that it has certain radius and certain linear boundaries, but you can easily custimize your boundaries. For instance, for a rectangular area, you may use:

```
if math.abs(relativePosition.x) < boxBoundary.x then
 if math.abs(relativePosition.y) < boxBoundary.y then
        returnMe = true
    end

end
```

Hope that may help!

Answer (score 0):

A BasePart doesn't have an event named "OnTouched", but I think you are referring to "Touched" event of BasePart.

You can change the `platform.OnTouched:Connect(fade)` to `platform.Touched:Connect(fade)`

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/BasePart/Touched

Answer (score 0):

With new r15 anthro models, sometimes the touch won't register as the hitbox fails to register a touch.

What I did a long ago was to create an invisible box with no collision that is thin above the part that you would like to touch, then check the .Touched event in the invisible box instead the one you are checking right now.

[image: You could use something similar to this, and make the box above transparent]